# reCaptcha TOTALMENTE invisível

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Estou fazendo uma página que vai enviar um formulário por Javascript (JQuery), não da forma comum . O intuito do feito é não precisar recarregar a página. Não estou conseguindo implementar o Invisible reCaptcha nesse sistema.

Após ler a documentação encontrei que este código é colocado no formulário e acredito que ele inclui o código ao enviar um formulário formulário.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"
     data-sitekey="your_site_key"
     data-callback="onSubmit"
     data-size="invisible">
</div>
```

A linha `data-callback="onSubmit"` chama tal função se o usuário "passar no teste". O que não ajuda muito no meu caso, sem contar que apesar se ser inivisible, ainda aparece o símbolo do do reCaptcha.

Pelo que entendi, logo ao carregar o reCaptcha ele já gera o código, porém preciso acessá-lo em um JavaSCript para enviá-lo ao servidor.

Se alguém souber alguma forma de resolver me ajude por favor. Gostaria de inclusive não incluir aquela div no HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri. Vou deixar a resposta caso seja a dúvida de mais alguém.

A div

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"
     data-sitekey="your_site_key"
     data-callback="onSubmit"
     data-size="invisible">
</div>
```

var ter que continuar no HTML.

Antes de chamar a API do reCaptcha coloquei um JavaScript com o código:

```
function onloadCallback() { // Callback
    $(function () { // Site carregado
        grecaptcha.execute(); // Executa o recaptcha
    });
}
```

E junto ao link da API passei um GET:

```
?onload=onloadCallback
```

O `onload=onloadCallback` faz com que a função `onloadCallback();` seja chamada assim que o cóidigo for carregado. Então ela faz a requisição do token assim que a página é carregada com `grecaptcha.execute();`. Depois é só pegar o código no momento que quiser com `grecaptcha.getResponse();`.

PS: Se o reCaptcha não tiver carregado ainda, e for feito um `grecaptcha.getResponse();`, ele vai retornar nulo. Para isso recomendo colocar um `if(grecaptcha.getResponse() !== "")` para garantir que não será enviado um token nulo.